# how to select those names from the field having only one part in them

Tags: mysql, sql

for example,
Name

```
ANU
ARUN RAJ
KARTHIK 
TESNA TITUS LESTU
```

What I want
Name

```
ANU
KARTHIK
```

Comment: Hint: without a <space>...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any errors? Please read documentation on SELECT commands and patterns for it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `not like`:

```
select name
from t
where name not like '% %'
```

Comment: If there are embedded spaces after the single words, then your not going to get any results... I've dealt with garbage data... :-)

Comment: What happens if it has space in the beginning?

Comment: Thnx, I got it.

Comment: how can ilist those names that does not have an initial ahead of them ex, From the names B.S.N PRAKASH and ARJUN I wish to select only ARJUN

Comment: why would not simply use trim? @Wanderer

Comment: @BibinMatthew : Thought `SQL Server`. My mistake

Comment: Its okay! TRIM is there in MSSQL as well :) @Wanderer

Comment: @BibinMatthew : But only for higher versions

Comment: @BibinMatthew . . . This will filter out names that have a space anywhere in the name, including the beginning and end.  That appear to be what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get name column with first name only

```
 SELECT Name FROM tableName where LOCATE(" ",TRIM(Name))>1;
```

Comment: this gives only the first letter of each name

Comment: first letter @Bibin Matthew